# Can't install spacy python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, windows, spacy

So, while installing spacy, I have got this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n0y5abli\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1 Check the logs for full command output.
```

```
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4cphnz1x\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1
       cwd: None
  Complete output (65 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting cython>=0.25
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (1.5 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.3.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
    Using cached preshed-3.0.2.tar.gz (167 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.2.tar.gz (35 kB)
  Collecting thinc==7.4.1
    Using cached thinc-7.4.1.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Collecting blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0
    Using cached blis-0.4.1.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.2.tar.gz (192 kB)
  Collecting catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7
    Using cached catalogue-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.7 kB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.19.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (10.9 MB)
  Collecting plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.50.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
  Collecting importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"
    Using cached importlib_metadata-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
  Collecting zipp>=0.5
    Using cached zipp-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cymem, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for murmurhash, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for thinc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for srsly, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, cython, cymem, murmurhash, preshed, numpy, blis, wasabi, srsly, zipp, importlib-metadata, catalogue, plac, tqdm, thinc
      Running setup.py install for cymem: started
      Running setup.py install for cymem: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ur6uxv4r\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ur6uxv4r\\cymem\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lp67dha5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4cphnz1x\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4cphnz1x\overlay\Include\cymem'
           cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ur6uxv4r\cymem\
      Complete output (18 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cymem
      running build_ext
      building 'cymem.cymem' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I am using the last Python 3.7.
Working on Windows 10.
Python is 64 bit.
I don't know what to do.
Also, I tried to reinstall Python, run cmd as admin, but it gives me the same error.
I also tried to search for the same problem but didn't find anything.
Help.

Comment: Did you do as the last line says: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"?

Comment: Yeah, second error is solved, but not first one

Comment: Have you tried `pip install wheel`?

Comment: @Andrew Morton , I will try tommorow

Comment: @AndrewMorton still giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result when installing (trying to install packages from source instead of binary wheels in windows) means that you're running 32-bit python and not 64-bit python.

Double-check that the `python` in your virtual environment is really 64-bit python. You can inspect `sys.maxsize` to check -- it should be `9223372036854775807`. Use `python -m pip` instead of just `pip` to be sure you're installing for the right venv for the `python` version that you just checked.

Comment: I am running python64

Comment: The next suggestion would be to upgrade pip with `pip install -U pip` and try installing again.

Comment: I have lastest pip

Comment: This line really makes it look like you're using 32-bit python: `c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was it